# Aggregating the probabilities of a classification forest to one average probability - why do I have a bias?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

Imagine a classification problem: a credit can default (or not).
My target variable is default (yes/no). 
If I train a tree or a logistic regression to predict default probabilities for each credit, than, the average PD over all credits in the training data is the same as the number of credits which defaulted divided by the number of all credits (which intuitively makes sense).

However, if I train a forest (consisting out of many classification trees), I loose this characteristic. I understand that it is not exactly the same due to out-of-bag samples, but shouldn't it be quite close? 
Right now, if 1.3% of the credits default in the training data, the mean of the predictions for the training data of log reg as well as the mean of the predictions of one tree result in 1.3%. However, the forest results are more around 1.4% (I trained the forest a thousand times and all results are in the interval of [1.37,1.43] - it cannot be a effect due to "randomness", though).

The same holds if I train regression trees (tree predicts the right average probability, a forest of many regression trees does not).

Node size seems to be a parameter which influences the mean prediction a lot but I do not understand why.

Does anyone have an explanation, why the forest significantly overestimates this probability and/or why it is dependent on node size?

I am using R, btw. but I guess it would be the same in python.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey @Jana, this does not seem like an `R` or generally a programming question, which would mean, this is not the right forum for the question.

Comment: Well, you might be right but I was wondering if its related to the way a random forest is coded in R. If I aggregate over all trees which - in theory - come to the true default rate. In average - shouldn't the forest come to the same result? 
Is this issue due to the out-of-bag sampling? But setting replace = FALSE does not change anything. 
If I do a CV (which actually is not necessary) the average probability over all observations is closer to the empirical default rate. 
You would help me a lot if one of you just have an idea what else I could try.

Comment: When you say you check the average PD - does it mean that you average the results of the PREDICTED CLASS from your model? Just to understand :)

Comment: Not of the predicted class but I average the predicted probabilities (thus, the majority voting of the trees)